# PDE with 3 variables, solved. Am I right?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics, linear-pde

I solved an exercise and I need to confront some other point of view.
Given this equation

$$u_x + u_y + u_z=0$$

I solved by using characteristics, obtaining

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}$$

i.e. the system

$$
\begin{cases}
dx=dy\\
dy=dz
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x=y+K_1\\
y=z+K_2
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
K_1=x-y\\
K_2=y-z
\end{cases}
$$

concluding as

$$
u(x,y,z)=\Phi(K_1+K_2)=\Phi(\Phi_1(x-y)+\Phi_2(y-z))
$$

with $\Phi, \Phi_1, \Phi_2: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $

In order to prove the solutions, I substituted them in the equality.

I computed the partial derivatives

$$u_x =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\Phi'(\Phi_1(x-y)+\Phi_2(y-z))\cdot(\Phi'_1(x-y))$$

$$u_y =\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\Phi'(\Phi_1(x-y)+\Phi_2(y-z))\cdot(-\Phi'_1(x-y)+\Phi'_2(y-z))$$

$$u_z =\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\Phi'(\Phi_1(x-y)+\Phi_2(y-z))\cdot(-\Phi'_2(y-z))$$

Computing the summations, result is zero, so the solutions seem correct.

Was I right in applying the method? Are the computations reported correct? Is there some theoretical passages I missed?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no aprior reason why $u$ should be separable in $K_1, K_2$. Any function of the form $u(x,y,z) = \Phi(K_1,K_2) = \Phi(x-y,y-z)$ also solve the PDE.

Comment: So, there is no reason to sum the constants.... thanks :)

Comment: @achillehui, last question: would you help me to understand how to compute each partial derivative of $\Phi(x-y,y-z)$? It's a compound function. How to use the chain rule?

Comment: Define $f(x,y,z) = x-y$, $g(x,y,z) = y-z$. Vew $u(x,y,z) = \Phi(x-y,y-z)$ as 
a composition of the function $(x,y,z) \mapsto (p,q) = (f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z))$ with $\Phi(p,q)$. The chain rule will take the form:
$$\begin{align}
\partial_x u &= (\partial_x f)(\partial_p \Phi) + (\partial_x g)(\partial_q \Phi) = +\partial_p \Phi + 0\\
\partial_y u &= (\partial_y f)(\partial_p \Phi) + (\partial_y g)(\partial_q \Phi) = -\partial_p \Phi + \partial_q \Phi\\
\partial_z u &= (\partial_z f)(\partial_p \Phi) + (\partial_z g)(\partial_q \Phi) = 0 -\partial_q \Phi\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Clear. I do owe you, thanks a lot.